# Grails 2.3.0 app has timeout and memory issues on Heroku

Tags: grails, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Grails 2.3.0 app to Heroku. When I was using Grails 2.2.x for the app, it deployed and ran fine. Now with 2.3.0, it fails with timeout and OOM errors. I have it set to use Java 7 in system.properties. Here's the errors I see when running "heroku logs --tail":

```
2014-12-05T00:08:24.391652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-12-05T00:08:29.983768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Xmx384m -Xms384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseCompressedOops -jar server/jetty-runner.jar --port 8749 target/*.war`
2014-12-05T00:08:30.507883+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2014-12-05T00:08:30.775203+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-12-05 00:08:30.772:INFO:omjr.Runner:Runner
2014-12-05T00:08:30.890872+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-12-05 00:08:30.890:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/app/target/happytrails-3.0.war!/ to /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8749-happytrails-3.0.war-_-any-/webapp
2014-12-05T00:08:30.775207+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-12-05 00:08:30.773:WARN:omjr.Runner:No tx manager found
2014-12-05T00:08:30.828575+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-12-05 00:08:30.828:INFO:omjr.Runner:Deploying file:/app/target/happytrails-3.0.war @ /
2014-12-05T00:08:30.852579+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-12-05 00:08:30.852:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2014-12-05T00:08:36.074408+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-12-05 00:08:36.074:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2014-12-05T00:08:44.993355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2014-12-05T00:08:44.992982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=517M(101.1%)
2014-12-05T00:08:46.932382+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-12-05 00:08:46.932:INFO:/:No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
2014-12-05T00:08:56.990777+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-12-05 00:08:56.990:INFO:/:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2014-12-05T00:09:05.200324+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=527M(103.1%)
2014-12-05T00:09:05.200631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2014-12-05T00:09:24.849286+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=564M(110.3%)
2014-12-05T00:09:24.849513+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2014-12-05T00:09:25.102440+00:00 app[web.1]: ... finished configuring Spring Security UI
2014-12-05T00:09:24.994440+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-12-05T00:09:25.102449+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-12-05T00:09:24.994449+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuring Spring Security UI ...
2014-12-05T00:09:30.388655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2014-12-05T00:09:30.388896+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2014-12-05T00:09:31.239678+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-12-05T00:09:31.250495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

heroku config shows the following variables:

```
BUILDPACK_URL:              https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-grails
JAVA_OPTS:                  -Xmx384m -Xms384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:          -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

The project I'm trying to deploy can be found on GitHub at https://github.com/jamesward/happytrails/tree/grails2.

Comment: The latest 2.3.x release is 2.3.11 - can you try it with that, or even something less recent but newer than the .0 release? May not help this particular issue, but you're likely to hit fixed bugs running old code.

Comment: With Xmx set to 384m and running memory at 564mb, it is likely that there is something allocating direct (non-heap) memory. Usually this is java.nio IO buffers.